# Selecting multible elements by ID (each one has unique ID)

Tags: jsoup

I have multiple elements on page and all of them have unique id something like that: title_1, title_2, title_n etc.

```
<a href="http://link" id="title_1">Link name</a>
<a href="http://link" id="title_2">Link name</a>
<a href="http://link" id="title_n">Link name</a>
```

Is this correct syntax for selecting these links?

```
a[id^=title]
```

IT seems to be not working.

Reference: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove that dot

```
a[id^=title]
```

Comment: Still not working. Tried a[id=title_421421] but still returning 0 elements. So it looks like there has to be some other way for wildcard'ish ID's...

Comment: @SYLARRR: try a[id="title 421421"]

Comment: Had doc.selectElementsById(a[id^=title]), not doc.select(a[id^=title]) which was causing this problem.